# How to pull Github branch project to replace the local files that I changed?

Tags: git, github, pycharm, branch, git-pull

I have a project with a branch.

I made local change.

I want to "go back" on my changes and get the cloud version.

I tried pull, it didn't changed my local files.

Question: How can I get the cloud files overwritting local files ?

Comment: What do you mean go back on your changes on your no update branch?I think your are confusing git pull with git revert or git reset(go back on your changes in your new branch).
Try to explain better your post and maybe we can help you. Anyways I recommend you do first a beginner tuto about git.

Comment: I edited my post. You are right, I need to do a tutorial because actually I'm confused on why a simple pull doesn't do the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-pull%5D+overwrite+local+files